# How do i improve this method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any better way to do this. I am looking for the alternate way to solve this problem

```
def validate_work_dates
    if ld_work_start_date.present? && off_work_date.present?
      if ld_work_start_date > off_work_date
        self.errors.add(:base, "Work start date can't be greater than off work date") and return false
      end
    elsif ld_work_start_date.present? && !off_work_date.present?
      self.errors.add(:base, "Off work date can't be blanck") and return false
    elsif off_work_date.present? && !ld_work_start_date.present?
      self.errors.add(:base, "Work start date cant't be clanck") and return false 
    end 
  end
```

Comment: what are the `ld_work_start_date` & `off_work_date` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rails presence validator for the start and end date.

```
validates :ld_work_start_date, presence: true
validates :off_work_date, presence: true
```

Then I would use your own validation method just to check the start date is before the end date.

```
validate :start_date_before_end_date, if: Proc.new{|x| x.ld_work_start_date.present? && off_work_date.present? }

def start_date_before_end_date
  if ld_work_start_date > off_work_date
    errors.add(:base, "Work start date can't be greater than off work date")
  end
end
```